# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method,and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

i have an action as :

```
           var viewModel = (from o in db.Sepet
                         join q2 in db.Urunler on o.urun_id equals q2.urun_id
                         join m in db.Markalar on q2.marka_id equals m.marka_id
                         where (o.sepet_id == bskt_id && o.statu == 0)
                         select new SepetView
                         {
                             urun_id = q2.urun_id,
                             urun_resmi = q2.resimlink,
                             urun_link = q2.urun_link,
                             urun_adi = q2.urun_adi,
                             urun_fiyat = FiyatGetir(q2.gununfirsati,q2.urun_fiyat,q2.kampanyafiyati),
                             adet = o.adet,
                             sepettutari = (o.adet * FiyatGetir(q2.gununfirsati, q2.urun_fiyat, q2.kampanyafiyati)),
                             marka_adi = m.marka_adi,

                         }).ToList();
```

and have a method (FiyatGetir) as :

```
        public static decimal FiyatGetir(DateTime tarih,decimal urunfiyat,decimal kampanyalifiyat)
    {
        decimal fiyat;
        if (tarih == DateTime.Now)
            fiyat = kampanyalifiyat;
        else
            fiyat = urunfiyat;
        return fiyat;
    }
```

it gives an error : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method,.....and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

How can i resolve that?

Comment: Use `.ToList()` to materialize the query to memory before your `.Select()`

Comment: I don't see how `tarih.Year` will ever equal `DateTime.Now` - did you mean `DateTime.Now.Year`?  You could try inlining the function using the conditional operator `?:` but accessing the `.Year` of a `DateTime` may not translate to SQL. You might also want to look up LINQKit.

Comment: not tarih.Year. it is tarih == DateTime.Now. I wrote it wrong to here

Comment: It could be because LINQ is actually converting the LINQ query to SQL query and what you are writing here is actually executed in the database.  This function may work if it is in the database but not here. I think a method defined in your code works on the values provided in LINQ where clause but not on sql table columns.  Also, DateTime.Now includes seconds so EQUAL will only work if the two datetimes are equal to the second.

Comment: well, can i use switch case statement or different method about this query?

Comment: Not tested but inline if/else might work: "urun_fiyat = (q2.gununfirsati == DateTime.Now) ? q2.kampanyafiyati : q2.urun_fiyat,".

Comment: yes, it works. thanks for your helpful..

Answer (score 1):

Everything between the parentheses is an expression. Entity Framework will try to translate this whole expression into SQL, which means that every part (token) of the expression must have an explicit mapping to a SQL equivalent. Of course, for `FiyatGetir` there isn't such a mapping because it's an unknown method (to EF).

As said in a comment, it's not hard to move the logic into the LINQ query itself, but you need it twice, so it's better to use the `let` keyword:

```
var viewModel = (from o in db.Sepet
                 join q2 in db.Urunler on o.urun_id equals q2.urun_id
                 join m in db.Markalar on q2.marka_id equals m.marka_id
                 where (o.sepet_id == bskt_id && o.statu == 0)
                 let fiyat = q2.gununfirsati == DateTime.Today 
                                              ? q2.kampanyafiyati
                                              : q2.urun_fiyat
                 select new SepetView
                 {
                     urun_id = q2.urun_id,
                     urun_resmi = q2.resimlink,
                     urun_link = q2.urun_link,
                     urun_adi = q2.urun_adi,
                     urun_fiyat = fiyat,
                     adet = o.adet,
                     sepettutari = (o.adet * fiyat),
                     marka_adi = m.marka_adi,

                 }).ToList();
```

Note that I changed the reference date/time to `DateTime.Today`. The chance that `q2.gununfirsati` exactly equals `DateTime.Now` is vitually zero, so I assume that's not correct. Maybe you should truncate `q2.gununfirsati` before the comparison (`DbFunctions.TruncateTime`).